# Referencing a User ID in a Create action in Node API

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating a To Do API to learn Node/Express (coming from Rails). I have a User model and a List model that will contain Items (tasks). Here's what my List schema looks like:

```
const listSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  items: [Item.schema],
  title: String,
  private: Boolean
});
```

As you can see, I'm referencing a User ID along with an embedded array of Items.

I'm trying to create a Create action in my `listController` that looks something like:

```
exports.createList = (req, res) => {
  const list = {
    user_id: //umm...
    title: req.body.title,
    private: req.body.private
  }
  List.create(list);
};
```

How can I include a reference to the (signed in) user_id? Would it be the front end app's job to send `user: user.id` if I include something like `user: req.body.user.id` to `list`?

Note: If it matters, I'm using passport-jwt for user auth.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have a user schema too. In that case, user_id would be the id that get from there. If you are not setting user_id manually, it most probably will be the mongodb object id.

Comment: Yes, I do have a user schema, but I don't understand how I can reference that user_id from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be the front end app's job to send user: user.id if I include something like user: req.body.user.id to list?

You shouldn't pass `userId` from the client - it's not secure. Take `userId` from the request itself. For authenticated requests you can fetch user from the `req` object - https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#authenticate-requests

Comment: Do you mean to pass in `passport.authenticate()` for my createList route so I can have access to `req.user.id`?

Comment: I mean executing `createList` only after authenticating the request. Like in the link from the answer